# smbmount fails to resolve hostname's address

Tags: windows, linux, networking, samba

I'm reading [this](http://www.freeos.com/articles/4310/) as a guide for accessing a Windows network from linux using samba.

The machine I want to access on my network is called `HP`, the following commands work fine:

```
smbclient -L HP
smbclient //HP/D
```

But, when I want to mount it, I get:

```
$ smbmount //HP/D /media/hp/d/
mount error: could not resolve address for HP: No address associated with hostname
No ip address specified and hostname not found
```

The error seems strange, if it can't resolve `HP`, how did smbclient read it?!

#### UPDATE

I don't want to specify the IP addresses manually because they tend to change every once in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's weird... normally smbmount can figure out names on its own. However, since it doesn't, you could use nmblookup to figure out which resolution methods work, and then use it as part of your mount command. For example, if you use a WINS server:

```
$ nmblookup -R -U 172.16.1.3 Haruhi
querying Haruhi on 172.16.1.3
172.16.1.3 Haruhi<00>
```

then you can extract it with a little shell work:

```
$ nmblookup -R -U 172.16.1.3 Haruhi | grep 'Haruhi<00>' | cut -d' ' -f1
172.16.1.3
```

so you can put it all together:

```
smbmount //HP/D /media/hp/d/ -o ip=`nmblookup -R -U 172.16.1.3 HP | grep 'HP<00>' | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

and thus you don't have an IP listed.

Comment: awesome! for some reason though nmblookup returned two lines with the ip and ending with `<00>` so I had to add -m 1 to grep

Comment: That is odd, maybe it got two answers? Wonder if its related to why smbmount isn't working like it should.

Comment: i get two lines from my samba server that has an aliased interface (eth0:0) on the same subnet as the real interface (eth0).  if i leave off the `-U` option only the real interface is returned, but with it both interfaces are listed.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian and probably others, install winbind:

```
apt-get install winbind
```

And check that "/etc/nsswitch.conf" has "wins" in the "hosts" line, as in:

```
hosts: files dns wins
```

This second one may already have been done for you.

The package creates the file /lib/libnss_wins.so

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/integrate-ms-networks.html#id2668413

You can then just add the entries to the /etc/fstab file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have winbind set up, attaching .local after the host name worked for me. 
For example:
sudo smbmount //mycomputername.local/storage /media/storage/

Comment: Works on Raspian/Debian Buster in September 2019

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to mount my media streamers samba share similiar to this.  The share is named playonhd and using the smbclient -L //playonhd works but

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //playonhd/HDD1 /mnt/box
```

does not.

My way around this without specifying an ip on the mount command is to use the alias I set up in /etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.27 box
```

Which allows

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //box/HDD1 /mnt/box
```

to be used.  I know the ip still has to be specified but in my case this was ok as it was already in the hosts file and I didn't want to specify it on the cl.

Comment: Greetings form the Future: I have had the same exact problem with a new install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 on VirtualBox with bridged connection, where with a new install on VMWare with the same 18.04.1 it works fine every time. Nothing I have tried gets it to work.

Comment: @Celess appreciation from the past (almost 10 years).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an IP address with the options switch, add this to the end:

```
-o ip=111.111.111.111
```

obviously replacing the IP with the appropriate server IP.

Comment: The IPs in the network are not exactly static, they take a while to change, but eventually they do change

Comment: well then that is another issue entirely, this will fix your connecting issue though.

Comment: Yes, it did work, thanks :) but I consider this a temporary/sub-optimal solution. Is there a way (using smbclinet for example) to automatically get the IP address of the machine and then pass it to the smbmount command through a pipe or something like that?

Comment: well you can assign it a static IP from your router. You can then edit the lmhosts file, this is basically the hosts file for samba. Alternatively if the windows box can access your PC, have it write its new IP to a file on your machine each boot perhaps? Then simply do something like this: smbmount //HP/D /media/hp/d/ -o ip=$(cat ~/somefile.txt | tr -d " ")

Comment: Also check out this article it seems to be a similar problem: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/mounting-samba-shares-under-opensuse-and-kubuntu-567168/

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems with hostname based `smbmount` mounting. Try `mount.cifs`, it works for me where `smbmount` doesn't.

Comment: got the same problem

Comment: So `mount.cifs` works? Problem solved? :)

Comment: lol, no dude it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the accepted answer, you can simply look up the IP address for WINS name `NAME` with `nmblookup NAME | grep 'NAME<00>' | cut -d' ' -f1`